# Is there a web application that lets me play my MP3 files right off the cloud?

Tags: mp3

Is there a web application that let Non-US people play MP3 files right off the cloud?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SugarSync offers 5GB of storage and a web based music player;

http://www.sugarsync.com/blog/2008/09/08/introducing-sugarsyncs-music-player/

[image]

You can sign up here; https://www.sugarsync.com/signup?startsub=5

Hope this helps.

**Referral Link Disclaimer**

Use this referral link; https://www.sugarsync.com/referral?rf=cbetc2vhetyxk&utm_source=txemail&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=referral - to get an extra 500MB of storage on sign up.

**Referral Link Disclaimer Ends**

Answer (score 5):

[Google Music Beta](http://music.google.com/) will let you store your music in the cloud and play it from a browser.

The problem is that you need to request an invite, and only in the US.

But You can get an invite using proxy , see this [link](http://www.dailyblogging.org/howto/get-google-music-invite-outside-us/)

**Note:** Google Music Beta is a fine proof of concept, letting you store your music in the cloud and play it from a browser, but getting all the music you want into it isn't practical yet, and some processes are slow. For now, Amazon Cloud Player is a better bet.

Comment: you mean its just an IP thing? do i need a US phone number to verify or what?

Comment: i couldn't actually try your solution because http://www.hidemyass.com/ does not have cookies enabled (alike most free proxies)

Comment: I guess you will have to wait so Google music will be for everyone.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  One that I am aware of is through [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_200593930_cloudplayer?nodeId=200593930#player).  You can upload your own content to it, too.

Comment: Amazon Cloud Player  for US only... z

Comment: @Pacerier Ok.  Perhaps you should edit your question to specify this limitation.